# Average of Numbers

Tags: average, word-problem

Consider the following problem:

if $a \leq b \leq c \leq d \leq e \leq f \leq 101$

and if average of these(a,b,c,d,e,f) numbers is 100 then what could be the least value of a?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{a+b+c+d+e+f}{6}=100\\
a=600-b-c-d-e-f$$

To make $a$ as small as possible, you should make $b,c,d,e$ and $f$ as large as possible, which would be $101$. This makes $a=95$.

Comment: That is pretty awesome man.